# Append Row in createRow Event

Tags: datatables

With jquery Datatable, I am trying to add new row in createdRow Event but it not adding.

Anything wrong here?

```
$("test").DataTable({
    "createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {

        $(row).after("<tr><td>test</td></tr>");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may assume that `createdRow` callback is called when `row` node is ready, yet not inserted into DOM, so the place, where this `.after()` refers to is not actually known.

As I tried to trick DataTable with something, like:

```
createdRow: row => {
    let newRowTemplate = document.createElement('template');
    newRowTemplate.innerHTML = `${row.innerHTML}<tr><td>test</td></tr>`;
    row = newRowTemplate.content.children;
}
```

I didn't succeed either since DataTable is probably filtering out `firstChild` out of HTMLCollection, so I cannot see the way of throwing in 2x `<tr>` nodes by this callback.

Workaround, I may think of, is using `row().child()`, which would give you the output you expect:

```
createdRow: (row, data, dataIndex) => {
    $('#test').DataTable().row(dataIndex).child('<tr><td>test</td></tr>').show();
}
```